# asp.net OwinContext Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

The OwinContext has a property call Authentication of type IAuthenticationManager, how can set this property with a class implemented by me instead of the default implementation.
I have search and search but didn't find any information that could help me....
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing I figure out the problem. On the startup of the owin authentication I has the following code
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
.....
CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always
.....
}

Because all the request were in http and not https the cookie didn't persist after the login.
Changing the enum to SameAsRequest, solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this is what you are looking for Custom Authentication using OwinContext.

https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Custom-Database-and-OWIN/

Just a thought, not a confirmed one - Ypu coould edit Owin Pipeline Configuration in **Startup.Auth.cs**:

```
public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
 {
     _container = new Container();
     _container.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(customAuthMgrInstance ); 
 }
```

and I assume it would replace the AuthenticationManager dependency for OwinContext. Please try and let me know, if that can be done. Couldn't try it out myself, as I do not have sufficient resources infront of me.

Comment: I already do that, what I want to do is on the OwinContext class replace the Authentication Property with my implementation

Comment: Yes. Owin uses default unity container for dependency injection, same approach.

Comment: Are you talking asp.net core or asp.net ?
My site is in asp.net

Comment: Yes, it should work on both.  But if you are not using DI container - follow this approach - https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Custom-Database-and-OWIN/

Comment: The approach does not replace the authenticationmanager object of the OwinContext object, although I can signin, but OwinContext.Request.User and OwinContext.Authentication.User are both null and so I can't valid if a user is authenticated

Comment: After some testing I figure out that the authentication cookie doesn't persist between calls.
I have this code on my login controller var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(new User { UserName = model.UserName, Password = model.Password }, Objects.Common.Consts.Constants.OWIN_AuthenticationCookieName);
            OwinContext.Authentication.SignOut(Objects.Common.Consts.Constants.OWIN_AuthenticationCookieName);
            OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(identity);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

Comment: After the login post back I see on fiddler that I have an authentication cookie "Set-Cookie: AuthCookie.....", but when I get to the index the AuthCookie no longer exists